# Solar variation tolerance for a solar panel

Tags: solar-cell, hardware, tolerance, panel

How to estimate average variation of input solar radiation that would be tolerable for a given solar panel? On what parameters will it depend?

Comment: Biggest will be night versus day...

Comment: Does it have to do with something like minimum solar radiation required to make the panel work?

Comment: Or how long the panel may be able to sustain the battery or system via battery when solar outage occurs?

Comment: @SolarMike  or during a continuous operation when the panel is charging a battery, the minimum solar radiation outage that could make it stop charging the battery? That will be equal to the minimum amout of irradiance that is required for the system to work? If so, then how to find it

Comment: The shadow of a tree will take your output to ZERO, if the cells are wired in series. Can you work with that?

Comment: oh I got it, there is no such thing as minimum radiation for which it works, the current flows only when there is light. But if there is load/battery, then in that case there is a minimum irradiation which would sustain/charge/make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit in how much light a solar panel can absorbs besides of heat limitation for the common crystalline silicon panels.

That being said, it will depend a lot of your solar panel technology, encapsulation and ambiant temperature.

There are several types of solar panels, the most common are thin films, crystalline silicon or concentration cells which can take very high irradiation, but needs optics and only works with a fairly direct irradiation.

The efficiency of solar panel reduce significantly with heat.

---

Edit following the comment:

It will start charging at fairly low irradiation, a few W/m2.

This is due because of the I-V properties of the photovoltaic cells. The current is linear to the irradiation at short circuit, but the voltage is almost directly at the Voc (maximum voltage) when the circuit is open and the panel receives some light.

If your system is directly connected to the battery, the panel voltage will be forced at the battery voltage and will supply current to the battery at its operating point for that voltage.

As soon you will have some light, a few W/m2, some current will flow into the battery as long as the Voc is higher than the battery voltage.